# how to decode russian language

Tags: android, unicode, utf-8

I have trying to load several sites with different languages content. And only russian content I have seen as `<?>` elements. Please help me to decode it to right symbols. My code samples:

```
RequestTask t = new RequestTask();
response = t.doIt("http://google.ru"); //troubles 
//response = t.doIt("http://stackoverflow.com"); //ok
//response = t.doIt("http://web.de/"); //ok
//response = t.doIt("http://www.china.com/"); // omg, it's ok too!

StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                    
    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
    out.close();
    String response_string = new String(out.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Request code:

```
public class RequestTask {
    public HttpResponse doIt(String... uri) 
    throws ConnectTimeoutException, UnknownHostException, IOException{
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 6000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 6000);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        Log.d(this.toString(), "HTTP GET to " + uri[0]);
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
        Log.d(this.toString(), "response: " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any troubles with `google.ru`:

```
$ wget google.ru
[...skipped....]
$ enca -L ru index.html 
MS-Windows code page 1251
  LF line terminators
```

you should always remember, there are at least 3 other more or less used encodings, that can be found on the pages with Russian content. Besides "UTF-8", I would most definitely check for "KOI-8R", "WIN-1251" and (not very popular) "Mac Cyrillic".

You might be better off using something like this:

```
encoding = ( "win-1251", "koi8-r" )  # maybe some others...

for enc in encoding:
    try:
        result = unicode( data, enc )
        break
    except:
        result = ""
        continue

if result:
    print name + "\t: " + enc
else:
    print name + "\t: unable to determine the encoding"
```

Comment: so, what is good practicle to do it? How I can determine encoding of page? Now I know two working methods -  `String response_string = new String(out.toByteArray(), "windows-1251");` and  `String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");`. But for using first method I need to determine encoding on response and I can't find suitable function for it. Second method is works, but it is correct to use it for any encoding?

Comment: the good practice is you don't know the page encoding and there's no reliable way to find out. sometimes the encoding will be specified in `meta` tags, sometimes not. see answer update for more code.

Comment: but where I can find the function like `unicode` which throws encoding exception in Java? Only what I have find is `Automatic detection of encoding` on url: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.ru/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html

Comment: oops, sorry. did not notice you're talking about java. `jchardet` sounds like a good start (http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/), but still it's a guesswork.